# Jquery mobile + phonegap only black theme

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova, phonegap-build

I've build a test app with phonegap build using only the jquery mobile example file.
In the browser the style is white (see the link: http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.2/dist/demos/examples/ ) but in the app i see the header and the buttons in the black version.
Anyone have some idea to solve this?
Tnx

Answer (score 0):

Did you try changing the `data-theme='a'`.  The data-theme controls what the buttons and background look like and Jquery mobile has created a standard set of swatches.  http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/api/themes.html - check this out for more information on changeing the colors or themeing.